# ObjectAnimator: View move animation from right to left

Tags: android

View move animation from the left to the right works ok

```
int startXposition = 5; // px
int endXposition = 960; // px

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
imageView.setImageResource(imageSrc);
params.setMargins(startXposition, 5, 0 ,0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
mMainRootContrainer.addView(imageView);
ObjectAnimator objectanimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "x", endXposition);
...
```

But how to animate from the right to the left? When start x position value bigger then end x position value?

```
int startXposition = 1800;
int endXposition = 960;
...
```

When I set it bigger animation doesn't appear at all;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it works I just forgot about my listener which removes visibilty of my imageView if start x position bigger then end x position

```
objectanimatorX.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        if (value >= endXposition) {
                            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

To move view from right-to-left

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
```